# How to detect googlebot and find out what pages have been crawled and everything else that has been done by the googlebot?

Tags: php, googlebot

I want to gather all data and use it for own purposes from my CRM.

Comment: From you access logs. Google bot uses a specific User-Agent header value, you can find all occurrences in the logs which should give you a complete overview.

Comment: Yes i know but i want to achieve something like this:
Lets say i have 3 websites i want to track all these websites and detect the google but with HTTP_USER_AGENT and get the logs and trough api send them to my CRM where i can render them in view. 

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("~google~is", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo "Find GoogleBot!";
}
```

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to check for keywords, "google" will be enough probably.